# Sonar 7.0: Unable to execute with maven

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
mvn clean install sonar:sonar  -X
```

the sonar plugin definition in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.905</version>
</plugin>
```

and i get this error:

```html
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar (default-cli) on project TestNGProject: Unable to execute SonarQube: Fail to parse entry in bootstrap index: <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" charset="UTF-8"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png"><link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png"><link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico"><meta name="application-name" content="SonarQube"/><meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#FFFFFF"/><meta name="msapplication-TileImage" content="/mstile-512x512.png"/><link href="/css/sonar.b5628b8d.css" rel="stylesheet"><title>SonarQube</title></head><body><div id="content"><div class="global-loading"><i class="spinner global-loading-spinner"></i> <span class="global-loading-text">Loading...</span></div></div><script>window.baseUrl=""</script><script src="/js/vendor.d9aca469.js"></script><script src="/js/app.b5628b8d.js"></script></body></html> -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: In settings.xml what have you set `sonar.host.url` to? Also, why have you [configured a plugin definition in your pom](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-GlobalSettings)?

Comment: I set sonar.host.url to send code analysis result to the sonaqube server

Comment: I changed my way to config sonarqube in my project.Instead of configuring a plugin definition in my pom ,I use sonar-project.properties and it worked